# How can I transfer GarageBand software instruments or find equivalents in Ableton Live?

Tags: instruments, ableton-live, garage-band

I'm switching from GarageBand to Ableton Live Standard for music production and live performance.  However, I'd still like to perform songs I've made using GarageBand.  I figure I can export loops or parts of the song from GarageBand and import that into Ableton Live, but I'd like to play the same (or very similar) software instruments as I had before.

I'm using macOS so I believe some GarageBand software instruments might be able to be imported into Ableton Live.  If this is the case, how can I import them?  If not, how can I identify similar software instruments in Live?

Comment: I believe there is a way to import apple esx samples into Live Sampler or Simpler. If I figure that out I will post here.

Comment: I have occasionally had luck loading GarageBand .exs files into Apple's pre installed AUSampler plugin.

Comment: How did you do it @Linuxios?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this question, and as far as I understand from my research: To properly import 3rd party sampler instruments into Ableton Live, you need the instrument "Sampler" which is included in Suite, or can be bought extra.

"Import third-party libraries or create and edit your own multisamples."
https://www.ableton.com/en/packs/sampler/